# Hosting through Cloudfront provides 403

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, namecheap

My question is about having AWS Cloudfront, a namecheap dns and an S3 bucket.

TLDR: When I try to access my website through my namecheap DNS, it throws a 403 ERROR with the message 'Bad request. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time' in my browser. However, when I access my website through the DNS provided by Cloudfront it works fine.

I have the following setup:

1. Namecheap domain name with a CNAME pointing to the AWS Cloudfront Distribution domain name
2. Cloudfront points to an S3 bucket that is hosting a static website (Bucket website endpoint)
3. There are two custom error responses that map 400 and 403 to a 200 OK and the /index.html
4. The bucket is set to 'public access', Block access is off
   I have the following policy on it as well:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadGetObject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::cryptocopytradeprod/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Everything works fine when I open the website from the bucket endpoint or the Distribution domain name from Cloudfront. However when I open the website from the Namecheap DNS it throws a 403. I have no idea why...

Comment: Sounds like you didnt add the alt name to cloudfront? (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/CNAMEs.html). FYI - if your using cloudfront s3 can/should be private, only cloudfront needs readonly access for this to work (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you please go through this?

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html

Also, we do not need to keep the bucket public when we use origin access control (OAC) and origin access identity (OAI).

> Also, you need to define Alternate domain names in CloudFront and use CloudFront Distributions Domain name as CName in NameCheap or even you can configure Cloudflare DNS for the same.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed setting the S3 to non-public and not to hosting a static website in combination with the bucket policy helped!